# How to handle an AdWords failure: request one report, receive a different report

Tags: xml, google-ads-api

Context: Adwords, XML, REST

We had the weirdest thing happen recently: We sent a report request (in a large batch of related requests) for an Account Performance Report and received an Ad Performance Report. Also the report request specified a single day, but the result specified a range of days.

This is the Account Performance Report XML:

```
<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201607">
    <selector>
        <fields>AccountCurrencyCode</fields>
        <fields>AccountDescriptiveName</fields>
        <fields>AccountTimeZoneId</fields>
        <fields>AdNetworkType1</fields>
        <fields>AdNetworkType2</fields>
        <fields>AverageCpc</fields>
        <fields>AveragePosition</fields>
        <fields>Clicks</fields>
        <fields>Conversions</fields>
        <fields>ConversionValue</fields>
        <fields>Cost</fields>
        <fields>CostPerConversion</fields>
        <fields>Ctr</fields>
        <fields>CustomerDescriptiveName</fields>
        <fields>Device</fields>
        <fields>ExternalCustomerId</fields>
        <fields>Impressions</fields>
        <fields>PrimaryCompanyName</fields>
        <fields>Slot</fields>
        <dateRange>
            <min>20150706</min>
            <max>20150706</max>
        </dateRange>
    </selector>
    <reportName>101_1_133_196</reportName>
    <reportType>ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
    <dateRangeType>CUSTOM_DATE</dateRangeType>
    <downloadFormat>TSV</downloadFormat>
</reportDefinition>
```

This is what came back.

```
"AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT (Jul 25, 2016-Jul 31, 2016)"
Campaign ID,Ad group ID,Ad ID,View-through conv.,Total conv. value,Day,Avg. position,Clicks,Impressions,Cost,Converted clicks,Conversions
Total, --, --,0,0.0, --,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0
ame Top vs. Other
Total    --  --  --  -- 0   0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0.00%    --  --  -- 0    --  --
```

Yes, there are appears to be some mangling of the data. However, the status code of the REST call was 200 so the report data was assumed to be correct. Subsequent processing revealed the fault.

This is the first time this has happened to us in all the years that we've been sending in this kind of report request. Is there anything I should be looking for with respect to incoming headers and the like that could be used to alert us to subsequent failures of this nature?

**SUBSEQUENTLY**

Oh dear, it happened again. I was rather hoping that this would be a one-off anomaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues was reported on the [AdWordsAPI](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/BXnAVhYe538) forum. See there for responses from Nadine Sundquist from the AdWords API Team acknowledging issue and fix.